# Jquery referring an object to itself the object is null - Browser Compatibilty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javaScript function that works in IE9 but doesn't work in Chrome, IE10 or IE11. You'd think there would be added functionality in the latest browsers so I'm confused.  The part that is giving me problems is when it refers to a passed in Object using Jquery.

Here is the signature to the function:

```
function updateDivViaAjaxWith3(url, divId, waitMsg, errMsg, scroll2, evalscripts, onSuccessFunc, formID, validateForm, delOper, optMsgDiv, disableAttribute, elementTypes,asyncInd)
```

I also put in an alert with the return value of 'frmCaseComment' for formID. 
This is the line that is giving me trouble(it's trying to perform the operation on a null value):

```
 var formElements = $(formID).serialize(true);
```

Here is the function call:

```
 updateDivViaAjaxWith3('${ajaxUrl}?action=2', 'compConfirmation', 'Saving.. Please wait..','','','true','', 'frmCaseComment','Y')
```

Does anyone know why this could be an issue or possibly a work around to referring to itself to serialize a form?

Thanks

Comment: please define "trouble". what's the value of formID before that assignment? what errors appear in the console?

Comment: serialize jQuery method doesn't accept any argument, but shouldn't be your issue, which is???

Comment: Are you sure `formId` has the correct value? Your function accepts **14** arguments that need to be passed in **in order**

Comment: So the value of formID is 'frmCaseComment' that was passed in but $(formID) is null. Null is the trouble. Can't perform serialize on a null value.

Comment: So it is: `$('#'+formID)`

Comment: Still null even if I add the '#'.

Comment: And just to clarify I know that the value is correct because I placed an alert before it to verify the value is in fact 'frmCaseComment'.

Comment: Can you show the function call? Because if any argument before `formId` is null, it will shift the values left.

Comment: Are you sure there is exactly one element on your page with the id `frmCaseComment`?

Comment: I figured out what it was... it was that the form didn't have an id.